# Proper use of async / await and Task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to learn those "new" keywords and tried to implement a simple async udp server.

```
public class UdpServerSync
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private CancellationToken _token;
    private UdpClient _client;

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start server");
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _token = _cts.Token;
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.25");
        var ip = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 7070);
        try
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (_client = new UdpClient(ip))
                {                        
                    while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        var receivedData = await _client.ReceiveAsync();
                        var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedData.Buffer);
                        // Process request e.g ProcessRequest(msg);
                        Console.WriteLine(msg);
                    }
                }
            }, _token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }    
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop server");
        if (_cts != null) _cts.Cancel();
    }
```

And then use it like this (for testing purpose):

```
var server = new UdpServerSync();
server.Start();
await Task.Delay(5000);
server.Stop();
```

The above code is just a proof of concept, its not about code review. By a simple udp server I mean a while loop with a udpclient listening for udp messages and writing them to the console - no processing or error handling.

The reason for the Task.Delay is just because its a proof of concept of calling  the server's start() and stop() methods.

To narrow down my questions:

1) if i was going to call the Start() and Stop() methods from e.g a WPF application´s start button, should I use server.Start() or Task.Run ? I don't want to await the call since there's no way to know how long the user is going to want the server started.

2) in the server code "ProcessRequest(msg), if that was a void method in another library, should I use Task.Run() to execute it to avoid the server thread being blocked or is there a better way ?

3) When we do async/await, does the code in the await statement execute in a new thread from the thread pool ?

4) Can I specify that the UdpServer is a long running process or it doesn't matter to the thread pool ?

Hope my question is more clear now, thanks guys :)

Comment: Your question is way too broad; try to be more specific. Also, if this is a code review, you should post it on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Does the code do what you want? What's the question here? But no, what you are doing doesn't look right. Waiting some period of time and hoping the task has finished is not right. You should provide a mechanism for the `server` to *tell you* when it's done. You could do that by returning the task from start so you can attach a continuation to it.

Comment: You seem to be doing normal threading. Your methods should be async and calling them should await (if you are returning something).

Comment: There's no such thing as a "simple async udp server". I recommend you start with something much simpler, like using `HttpClient` to retrieve a web page asynchronously.

Comment: I edited my post with exact questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) if i was going to call the Start() and Stop() methods from e.g a WPF application´s start button, should I use server.Start() or Task.Run ?

With the code you have now, you can just call `Start` (which calls `Task.Run`). IMO, the call to `Task.Run` is unnecessary. And the call to `ConfigureAwait` is *definitely* unnecessary since there's no `await` to configure.

> I don't want to await the call since there's no way to know how long the user is going to want the server started.

But you probably *do* want to know about any exceptions. So, think about how to handle those. One solution is to save the returned `Task` as a property. Or, you could just `await` it (remember, it doesn't matter "how long" it runs, because it's an *asynchronous* wait).

> 2) in the server code "ProcessRequest(msg), if that was a void method in another library, should I use Task.Run() to execute it to avoid the server thread being blocked or is there a better way ?

There's no "server thread". But if `ProcessRequest` takes a long time, then you might want to consider using `Task.Run` so that your code will accept the next request while processing that one.

> 3) When we do async/await, does the code in the await statement execute in a new thread from the thread pool ?

No. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that goes into more detail.

> 4) Can I specify that the UdpServer is a long running process or it doesn't matter to the thread pool ?

It doesn't matter.